# how to rename USB devices permanently for their displayed named in VMWare Workstation

Tags: usb, vmware, vmware-workstation, rename

How do I rename the displayed name of USB devices shown in VMware workstation?

Example in screenshot. I want to rename (permanently, so that it remembers between the decive being plugged and unplugged) which device is which, as I have multiple of the same devices. They are all Huawei mifi networking USB's, and all appear in the bottom right on workstation with the same name "Huawei USB composite Device".

I have tried looking at them in the registry, but their freindly names are not being used here. I don't know where this string is coming from. I have downloaded and run USB Deview from nirsoft (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html), and all of the information that pulls up for the device, no string matches what workstation is showing here, so I have nothing to edit as I cannot find what it is referencing to get that string.

I currently use 3 of these at the same time, and need to swap them frequently, so knowing which is which is going to be really useful to me.

[image]

Comment: any solution yet?

Comment: Nope, nothing yet.